# Flagged answer was not the answer I was looking for

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, not-an-answer

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904885/how-to-break-out-of-this-loop). One of the answers that is currently there, I had flagged as "Not an Answer", because as I state in comments, I wasn't looking for a solution to the problem I was attempting, I was asking why my stack was blowing up (I learned about stack limits that day).

My flag has since then been disputed. The user even states that he is solving the Euler problem.

When I flagged it, the description for "Not an Answer" is "`This is a posted answer, but doesn't attempt to answer the question.`" So, since the user even stated he's going against my wishes by supplying me an attempted solution to my Euler problem, why was this flag disputed?

On this note, I'd like to suggest that if the asker of the question is flagging an answer as "Not an Answer", they should be able to explain why they are flagging it such.

Comment: Are you complaining about the answer because you don't really want to see the answer (ie, the point of the Euler problems is to solve them yourself)?  You might point that out in your reason for flagging (choosing 'other' rather than 'not an answer').

Comment: You're correct. I asked not to be provided an answer for the Euler problem. It's even posted. Several who did provide one even deleted their answers. I honestly hadn't thought of using the "other" option, as "Not an Answer" seemed appropriate. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Moderators have something like 10 seconds to handle a flag; they're not going to have time to really understand why you're flagging it for something complicated like this without more background information (ie, 'other').

Comment: Euler problems are popular. People like helping, and people like showing off. If you do not want an answer to the euler problem, maybe next time don't *tag* it project-euler and don't *show* code that indicates it's euler. Rename everything. Create a different repro. If you're avoiding all solutions, don't invite them. FYI for next time.

Comment: @Joe - In this case, it's more than just a matter of time. When you flag an answer, you're asking us to unilaterally delete content that someone has contributed. If it's a legitimate attempt to provide a solution, I'm not going to delete it and punish the person for taking the time to answer. I would decline even a custom flag asking for this to be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not how the "not an answer" flag works. If the answerer attempted to answer the question, it is an answer. If you don't find it to be a helpful answer, just downvote it.

The "not an answer" flag is for posts that don't attempt to answer the question, such as when people attempt to comment on the original post by using the answer functionality.

As noted by the Knights who say Ni, the flag should not require a moderator to evaluate the technical merit of the answer in relation to the question.

Comment: Short addendum: The reason being that moderators' purpose is not to judge the helpfulness of an answer - if it attempts to answer, it doesn't qualify for "not an answer."

Comment: But he's not attempting to answer my question at all. He's attempting to help me solve the Euler problem.

Comment: "Not an answer" really means "this is not the answer to ANY question".

Comment: @Joe: Then the description should say that, but instead says "the question", which I take to mean the question I asked.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P if you feel that way then your best option is to vote the answer down as not useful to you.  Flags should be used where moderator intervention is required.

Comment: @Rory: I did vote it down, but it don't matter cause someone gave him an upvote.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P Remember that your question is also for the benefit of anyone else searching for it in the future too - just because you didn't *want* that particular solution doesn't mean it isn't of worth to other people and doesn't mean it should be deleted by a moderator

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer is for stuff like

- "Please help me, I have the same problem"
- "I have a question: can you foo a bar?"
- "Does the foo say bar when you baz it?" (should be comment)
- "I like unicorns"

Please only flag when it clearly does not even attempt to answer your question in any way. Mods should not have to judge if the answer is **right or wrong**, just if the answer is an answer at all.